# How I can get positive numbers from a String and separates with commas

Tags: regex, oracle

I have the following problem in Oracle, I cannot get the following through regex:

For example, I have this String:

```
C_1 + 123 * C_2 * 4332
```

How can I get the following result?

```
123,4332
```

Right now what I have done is:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('C_1 + 123 * C_2 * 4332','C_[0-9.]+|[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]', '') FROM DUAL;
```

But in this case, I get `1234332`.

Comment: You say "numbers" but your example only has non-negative integers. Can your inputs, in fact, include fractional numbers like 32.96? Can they include negative numbers? The highly-upvoted solution (which you already marked as "correct") would not work in this more general case; it only works if all your numeric inputs are non-negative integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT trim(BOTH ',' FROM regexp_replace('C_1 + 123 * C_2 * 4332', '(C_\S+|\D)+', ',')) FROM DUAL;
```

See the [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7050c2b834bda9283226f2b344341ba2).

The `(C_\S+|\D)+` regex matches one or more repetitions of `C_` followed with one or more non-whitespace chars or any non-digit char, and the matches are replaced with a single `,`.

As the match can occur at the start or end of string, the `trim` function is used to post-process the `regexp_replace` result.